# ffmpeg messes up delayed inputs (repeats at the beginning)

Tags: ffmpeg

ffmpeg plays audio inputs delayed to t1, t2 etc at t=0.
If there are several inputs, then it replicates one after the other (after in0 finishes with its duration duration(in0), plays another one at t=duration(in0), etc.)

In the following example, the in0 is played at t=0.

```
ffmpeg -i in0.mp3 -i in1.mp3 -i in2.mp3 -filter_complex "[0]adelay=1000[delayed1];[1]adelay=2000[delayed2];[2]adelay=3000[delayed3];[delayed1][delayed2][delayed3]amix=inputs=3:duration=longest" -codec:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 output.mp3
```

The command performs the following: 1. The ffmpeg processes three input files (mp3). 2. The complex filter delays the inputs by 1, 2, 3 seconds input-wise. 3. amix mixes the delayed outputs together. 4. And finally, a coded transforms it into an output mp3.

Another short version: 2 delayed beeps, an finally there come 3 beeps out (@ 0, 1, 2 seconds):

```
ffmpeg -i beep.mp3 -filter_complex "[0]adelay=1000[delayed1];[0]adelay=2000[delayed2];[delayed1][delayed2]amix=inputs=2:duration=longest" -codec:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 output.mp3
```

ffmpeg version N-110011-gf456c192d9-tessus on a Mac M1, downloaded as binary from https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg (01.2023).

I added also a silent input file from 0 to 1 seconds without any alteration of the outcome.
I added a silent stream as input as well without improvement. E.g.:

```
... -filter_complex "aevalsrc=0:d=4[silence];...
```

Another test with another ffmpeg version 5.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers  built with Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5):
`ffmpeg -i beep.mp3 -filter_complex "[0]adelay=1000[delayed1];aevalsrc=0:d=5[silence];[silence][delayed1]amix=inputs=2:duration=longest" -codec:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 output.mp3`
There are again 2 beeps, at 0 and 1 second.

(comment: concat solves the issue. But I want to have a flexible solution with possibly overlapping audio streams.) Thanks for giving a hint!

Comment: I ran your command with [this file](https://www.soundjay.com/buttons/beep-01a.mp3) and it worked. i only hear it 3 times, at 1, 2 and 3 second. there is no sound at 0

Comment: So many thanks! So, the command is correct? Why is this issue with my ffmpeg on Mac?

Comment: Well it works so I believe it to be correct. I made 3 copies of that file and ran command. I ran it on ubuntu 22 with ffmpeg version  4.4.2. Try running the command on other machine, a vm or a docker. Also have you tried running it with file i linked in previous comment? did it work with that file?

Comment: I submitted a bug report to the dev team. With version 4.4 it appears as well